# Use JQuery natural interface of color picker in primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces 3.5, Mojara 2.1.21, Omnifaces 1.5

I want to use Primefaces component color picker to select a color and update a color in a text box.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.color}" id="colorId"/>
<p:colorPicker value="#{bean.color}" />
```

So the question how can I update the value (I need it only client side) in h:outputText.

The  JQuery color picker component has a nice inteface to do this. But how can I use it ? How can I registry onChange event in color picker of generated component ?

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking on web for your problem, but also couldn't find any useful solution. So I dicided to use same approach as in this my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587177/avoid-focus-in-datatable-filter-in-dialog/18590876#18590876).

Here is my suggestion:

Take JS code from primefaces and rewrite it:

```
        <h:form prependId="false">

                <h:outputText value="t#{testas.color}" id="colorId3"/>
                <p:colorPicker id="cid" value="#{testas.color}" widgetVar="co" />           

        </h:form>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        PrimeFaces.widget.ColorPicker = PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend({

            init: function(cfg) {
                this._super(cfg);

                this.input = $(this.jqId + '_input');
                this.cfg.popup = this.cfg.mode == 'popup';    
                this.jqEl = this.cfg.popup ? $(this.jqId + '_button') : $(this.jqId + '_inline');
                this.cfg.flat = !this.cfg.popup;
                this.cfg.livePreview = false;
                this.cfg.nestedInDialog = this.jqEl.parents('.ui-dialog:first').length == 1;

                this.bindCallbacks();

                //ajax update check
                if(this.cfg.popup) {
                    this.clearOrphanOverlay();
                }

                //create colorpicker
                this.jqEl.ColorPicker(this.cfg);

                //popup ui
                if(this.cfg.popup) {
                    PrimeFaces.skinButton(this.jqEl);
                    this.overlay = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(this.jqEl.data('colorpickerId')));
                    this.livePreview = $(this.jqId + '_livePreview');
                }
            },

            bindCallbacks: function() {
                var _self = this;

                this.cfg.onChange = function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    _self.input.val(hex);

                    if(_self.cfg.popup) {

                        _self.livePreview.css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                    }
                };

                this.cfg.onShow = function() {
                    if(_self.cfg.popup) {
                        _self.overlay.css('z-index', ++PrimeFaces.zindex);
                    }

                    var win = $(window),
                    positionOffset = _self.cfg.nestedInDialog ? '-' + win.scrollLeft() + ' -' + win.scrollTop() : null;

                    if(_self.cfg.nestedInDialog) {
                        _self.overlay.css('position', 'fixed');
                    }

                    //position the overlay relative to the button
                    _self.overlay.css({
                                left:'',
                                top:''
                        })
                        .position({
                            my: 'left top'
                            ,at: 'left bottom'
                            ,of: _self.jqEl,
                            offset : positionOffset
                        });
                }

                this.cfg.onHide = function(cp) {
                    _self.overlay.css('z-index', ++PrimeFaces.zindex);

                    $('#colorId3').html(_self.input.val()); // -> ADDED BY ME

                    $(cp).fadeOut('fast');
                    return false;
                }
            },

            /**
             * When a popup colorpicker is updated with ajax, a new overlay is appended to body and old overlay
             * would be orphan. We need to remove the old overlay to prevent memory leaks.
             */
            clearOrphanOverlay: function() {
                var _self = this;

                $(document.body).children('.ui-colorpicker-container').each(function(i, element) {
                    var overlay = $(element),
                    options = overlay.data('colorpicker');

                    if(options.id == _self.id) {
                        overlay.remove();
                        return false;   //break;
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        </script>
```

I added this part: $('#colorId3').html(_self.input.val());

I hope someone, who knows JQuery (I am not), will can write compact script to this function. But this worked for me.

Give me opinions on this please ;) I am new here too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Interesting approach. Principally my question is answered. But I have on my page more than one colorPicker. So I'll try to adapt your answer. If I found (or not found) one I write it here too.

Comment: Maybe someone can tell more about this answer. And as I said, I am not good at JQuery, but maybe you can pass variable of input id or look at colorPicker id or name and then decide, which input update. This is just guess :)